# Having difficulty to reinitialise jscrollpane scroller

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use jscrollpane in my horizontal divison where jscroll help to scroll .
Problem is divison data is loaded with the help of ajax. And jscrollpane doesn't show scrollbar until the width of browser is changed.

As i am using

```
api.reinitialise();
```

Method to reinitialise scrollbar on width change. So can anyone provide me solution so that once a data is loaded with the help of ajax after that it automatically reinitialise and shows me the scroll bar.

Also i load the data from json and parse it so it takes time to load into browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialise jscrollpane scrollers after ajax data is loaded. if you use jscrollpane before. it wont show.

Thats why when you resize the browser window the api.reinitialise(); works to load jscrollpane automatically and adjust its width with respect to browser window.

Call jscrollpane when your ajax data is loaded into division.

For eg

```
$('#div').load('x.json');
$('#div').jScrollPane();

or


$('#div').load('x.json').jScrollPane();
```